# How do I count subquery CASE WHEN categories with an outer query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, count, sql-server-2012, subquery

I have a sample set of data in this [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=d2364215968c1a3a888407756117c39a).  The data represents a batch of wells that fall into different well-type categories based on some criteria.  I am trying to group the wells by the category they fall into and then count how many wells are in each category based on another set of criteria.

My current query partially works but only correctly counts wells that are higher in the `CASE WHEN` clause hierarchy.  This is because the first `CASE WHEN` has the chance to assign well categories to all of the wells in the data set.  However, as it goes through each `CASE WHEN` clause, the query "see's" fewer wells because it runs out of wells it can assign a category to.  By the time it reaches the end, almost all of the wells have already had a category assigned to them, preventing some category counts from occurring at all.

Here is the current query I have, which is also in the db<>fiddle link above:

```
SELECT
    dt.WellCategory,
    ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN dt.LeaseType IN ('F','I','S','P') OR dt.LeaseType NOT IN ('F', 'I', 'S', 'P', 'U') THEN 1 END), 0) AS [Number of Wells], -- Federal + Indian + State + Fee + Multi-Lease
    ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN dt.LeaseType = 'F' THEN 1 END), 0) AS [Federal], -- Sums up how many wells from the subquery have a leasetype of "Federal"
    ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN dt.LeaseType = 'I' THEN 1 END), 0) AS [Indian],
    ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN dt.LeaseType = 'S' THEN 1 END), 0) AS [State],
    ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN dt.LeaseType = 'P' THEN 1 END), 0) AS [Fee (Private)],
    ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN dt.LeaseType NOT IN ('F', 'I', 'S', 'P', 'U') THEN 1 END), 0) AS [Multiple Lease Types]
FROM
(
    SELECT -- Subquery labels wells according to their wellstatus, welltype, etc.
        c.LeaseType,
        CASE 
            WHEN w.WellStatus = 'p' AND w.WellType = 'gw' OR ((w.WellStatus = 'pai' OR w.WellStatus = 'pii') AND (w.WellType = 'gwi' OR w.WellType = 'ggi' OR w.WellType = 'gwd')) THEN 'Producing Gas Wells'
            WHEN w.WellStatus = 'p' AND w.WellType = 'ow' OR ((w.WellStatus = 'pai' OR w.WellStatus = 'pii') AND (w.WellType = 'owi' OR w.WellType = 'ogi' OR w.WellType = 'owd')) THEN 'Producing Oil Wells'
            WHEN w.WellStatus = 's' AND w.WellType = 'ow' OR ((w.WellStatus = 'sai' OR w.WellStatus = 'sii') AND (w.WellType = 'owi' OR w.WellType = 'ogi' OR w.WellType = 'owd')) THEN 'Shut-In Oil Wells'
            WHEN w.WellStatus = 's' AND w.WellType = 'gw' OR ((w.WellStatus = 'sai' OR w.WellStatus = 'sii') AND (w.WellType = 'gwi' or w.WellType = 'ggi' or w.WellType = 'gwd')) THEN 'Shut-In Gas Wells'
            WHEN w.WellStatus = 'a' AND w.WellType = 'wi' THEN 'Active Water Injection Wells'
            WHEN w.WellStatus = 'a' AND w.WellType = 'gi' THEN 'Active Gas Injection Wells'
            WHEN w.WellStatus = 'a' AND w.WellType = 'wd' THEN 'Active Water Disposal Wells'
            WHEN w.WellStatus = 'a' AND w.WellType = 'gs' THEN 'Active Gas Storage Wells'
            WHEN w.WellStatus = 'a' AND w.WellType = 'ws' THEN 'Active Water Source Wells'
            WHEN w.WellStatus = 'a' AND w.WellType = 'tw' THEN 'Active Test Holes'
            WHEN w.WellStatus = 'i' AND w.WellType = 'wi' THEN 'Inactive Water Injection Wells'
            WHEN w.WellStatus = 'i' AND w.WellType = 'gi' THEN 'Inactive Gas Injection Wells'
            WHEN w.WellStatus = 'i' AND w.WellType = 'wd' THEN 'Inactive Water Disposal Wells'
            WHEN w.WellStatus = 'i' AND w.WellType = 'gs' THEN 'Inactive Gas Storage Wells'
            WHEN w.WellStatus = 'i' AND w.WellType = 'ws' THEN 'Inactive Water Source Wells'
            WHEN w.WellStatus = 'i' AND w.WellType = 'tw' THEN 'Inactive Test Holes'
            WHEN w.WellStatus = 'ta' THEN 'Temporarily-Abandoned Wells'
            WHEN w.WellStatus = 'pa' THEN 'Plugged and Abandoned Wells'
            WHEN c.LateralStatus = 'NEW' THEN 'New Permits - Not Yet Approved'
            WHEN c.LateralStatus = 'APD' THEN 'Permits Approved - Not Yet Commenced'
            WHEN c.LateralStatus = 'DRL' THEN 'Drilling Commenced - Not Yet Completed'
            WHEN c.LateralStatus = 'OPS' THEN 'Drilling Operations Suspended'
            WHEN w.WellStatus IN ('drl','ops','p','s','ta','pai','pii','sai','sii','a','i') AND w.Operator = 101600 THEN 'Open Orphan Wells (no known operator)'
            WHEN w.WellStatus IN ('drl','ops') THEN 'Total Holes Not Yet Completed'
            WHEN ((w.WellStatus = 'p' or w.WellStatus = 's') AND w.WellType <> 'LI') OR (w.WellStatus = 'pai' OR w.WellStatus = 'pii' OR w.WellStatus = 'sai' OR w.WellStatus = 'sii') THEN 'Total Wells Capable of Production'
            WHEN (w.WellStatus = 'drl' OR w.WellStatus = 'ops' OR ((w.WellStatus = 'p' or w.WellStatus = 's') AND w.WellType <> 'LI') OR w.WellStatus = 'ta' OR w.WellStatus = 'pai' OR w.WellStatus = 'pii' OR w.WellStatus = 'sai' OR w.WellStatus = 'sii' OR w.WellStatus = 'a' OR w.WellStatus = 'i') THEN 'Total Non-Plugged Wells'
            WHEN (w.WellStatus = 'drl' or w.WellStatus = 'ops' or ((w.WellStatus = 'p' or w.WellStatus = 's') and w.WellType <> 'LI') or w.WellStatus = 'ta' or w.WellStatus = 'pai' or w.WellStatus = 'pii' or w.WellStatus = 'sai' or w.WellStatus = 'sii' or w.WellStatus = 'a' or w.WellStatus = 'i' or w.WellStatus = 'pa') THEN 'Total Wells Drilled'
        END AS WellCategory
    FROM HWell w
        LEFT JOIN HConstruct c ON c.WellKey = w.PKey
) dt
GROUP BY dt.WellCategory
ORDER BY dt.WellCategory DESC
```

Here is the table the query above produces:

**Table #1**

| WellCategory | Number of Wells | Federal | Indian | State | Fee (Private) | Multiple Lease Types |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Total Wells Capable of Production | 2 | 2 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| Temporarily-Abandoned Wells | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| Shut-In Oil Wells | 21 | 10 | 10 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| Shut-In Gas Wells | 26 | 19 | 2 | 4 | 1 | 0 |
| Producing Oil Wells | 59 | 18 | 25 | 6 | 10 | 0 |
| Producing Gas Wells | 90 | 59 | 1 | 25 | 5 | 0 |
| Plugged and Abandoned Wells | 113 | 60 | 15 | 19 | 19 | 0 |
| Permits Approved - Not Yet Commenced | 14 | 4 | 2 | 2 | 4 | 2 |
| New Permits - Not Yet Approved | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| Inactive Water Injection Wells | 18 | 11 | 5 | 2 | 0 | 0 |
| Drilling Operations Suspended | 4 | 1 | 3 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| Drilling Commenced - Not Yet Completed | 4 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 2 | 0 |
| Active Water Injection Wells | 6 | 1 | 5 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| Active Water Disposal Wells | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| NULL | 140 | 83 | 28 | 14 | 15 | 0 |

Here is the table I know the same data set can produce and the one I want to replicate:

**Table #2**

| Well Statuses | Number Of Wells | Federal | Indian | State | Fee (Private) | Multiple Lease Types |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Producing Oil Wells | 59 | 18 | 25 | 6 | 10 | 0 |
| Producing Gas Wells | 90 | 59 | 1 | 25 | 5 | 0 |
| Shut-In Oil Wells | 21 | 10 | 10 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| Shut-In Gas Wells | 26 | 19 | 2 | 4 | 1 | 0 |
| Active Water Injection Wells | 6 | 1 | 5 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| Active Gas Injection Wells | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| Active Water Disposal Wells | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| Active Gas Storage Wells | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| Active Water Source Wells | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| Active Test Holes | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| Inactive Water Injection Wells | 18 | 11 | 5 | 2 | 0 | 0 |
| Inactive Gas Injection Wells | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| Inactive Water Disposal Wells | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| Inactive Gas Storage Wells | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| Inactive Water Source Wells | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| Inactive Test Holes | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| Temporarily-Abandoned Wells | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| Plugged and Abandoned Wells | 113 | 60 | 15 | 19 | 19 | 0 |
| New Permits - Not Yet Approved | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| Permits Approved - Not Yet Commenced | 14 | 4 | 2 | 2 | 4 | 2 |
| Drilling Commenced - Not Yet Completed | 4 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 2 | 0 |
| Drilling Operations Suspended | 4 | 1 | 3 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| Open Orphan Wells (no known operator) | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| Total Holes Not Yet Completed | 8 | 2 | 4 | 0 | 2 | 0 |
| Total Wells Capable of Production | 198 | 108 | 38 | 35 | 17 | 0 |
| Total Non-Plugged Wells | 232 | 123 | 52 | 38 | 19 | 0 |
| Total Wells Drilled | 345 | 183 | 67 | 57 | 38 | 0 |

Table #2 is generated using a much longer query that uses several subqueries and temp tables to count how many wells belong to each category using their `DISTINCT w.WellID`.  In addition, the full data set has a lot more entries, usually each category has at least some wells in it and not so many "0's".

I don't know how to tell the query to count wells more than once if they fall into several well categories without making the query super long and start introducing temp tables, which I would prefer not to do.  *NOTE I do not want to count a well twice for same category, only count it once per category.

Comment: You may have said this, and I missed it. But is it possible for a well to exist in multiple categories?

Comment: @ChadBaldwin Yes, one well can occur in more than one category at the same time but it can only be counted once/category.

Comment: Ah okay, so that explains the issue. You need to count categories that can exist for multiple wells, but the CASE statement will only return the first Category that hits. So you'll need a solution that is able to produce duplicates by Category. I'll see what I can figure out.

Comment: @ChadBaldwin I think so... One well could meet the criteria of several CASE statements.  However, in my query, once the first case statement is satisfied, the well category is assigned and can't be assigned to another category.  Once its to the last CASE statement, there are barely any wells to assign anymore.

Comment: Yup, I think I get it. So if you have 1 well, that is a "Producing Gas Wells" as well as a "Permits Approved", then you want to count it in both categories. But because of the way CASE statements work...it will only count for "Producing Gas Wells"

Comment: @ChadBaldwin Exactly!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239496/discussion-between-chad-baldwin-and-hiebs915).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way you could do it while keeping it somewhat easy to read:

I broke the `CASE` statement into logical pieces. Parts that don't overlap but seem related go into their own query to determine the category. Then I `UNION ALL` them together to avoid de-duping.

There's tons of ways this could be done, and this is just one of them...

Also, like I mentioned in the chat session, if you are able to, I would highly recommend working on normalizing this data, creating lookup tables, etc.

```sql
WITH cte_Wells AS (
    SELECT w.WellStatus, w.WellType, c.LateralStatus, c.LeaseType, w.Operator
    FROM dbo.HWell w
        LEFT JOIN dbo.HConstruct c ON c.WellKey = w.PKey
)
SELECT
    dt.WellCategory,
    ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN dt.LeaseType IN ('F','I','S','P') OR dt.LeaseType NOT IN ('F', 'I', 'S', 'P', 'U') THEN 1 END), 0) AS [Number of Wells], -- Federal + Indian + State + Fee + Multi-Lease
    ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN dt.LeaseType = 'F' THEN 1 END), 0) AS [Federal], -- Sums up how many wells from the subquery have a leasetype of "Federal"
    ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN dt.LeaseType = 'I' THEN 1 END), 0) AS [Indian],
    ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN dt.LeaseType = 'S' THEN 1 END), 0) AS [State],
    ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN dt.LeaseType = 'P' THEN 1 END), 0) AS [Fee (Private)],
    ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN dt.LeaseType NOT IN ('F', 'I', 'S', 'P', 'U') THEN 1 END), 0) AS [Multiple Lease Types]
FROM (
    SELECT w.LeaseType, x.WellCategory
    FROM cte_Wells w
        CROSS APPLY (
            SELECT WellCategory = CASE 
                                    WHEN w.WellStatus = 'p' AND w.WellType = 'gw' OR (w.WellStatus IN ('pai','pii') AND w.WellType IN ('gwi','ggi','gwd')) THEN 'Producing Gas Wells'
                                    WHEN w.WellStatus = 'p' AND w.WellType = 'ow' OR (w.WellStatus IN ('pai','pii') AND w.WellType IN ('owi','ogi','owd')) THEN 'Producing Oil Wells'
                                    WHEN w.WellStatus = 's' AND w.WellType = 'gw' OR (w.WellStatus IN ('sai','sii') AND w.WellType IN ('gwi','ggi','gwd')) THEN 'Shut-In Gas Wells'
                                    WHEN w.WellStatus = 's' AND w.WellType = 'ow' OR (w.WellStatus IN ('sai','sii') AND w.WellType IN ('owi','ogi','owd')) THEN 'Shut-In Oil Wells'
                                    WHEN w.WellStatus = 'a' AND w.WellType = 'wi' THEN 'Active Water Injection Wells'
                                    WHEN w.WellStatus = 'a' AND w.WellType = 'gi' THEN 'Active Gas Injection Wells'
                                    WHEN w.WellStatus = 'a' AND w.WellType = 'wd' THEN 'Active Water Disposal Wells'
                                    WHEN w.WellStatus = 'a' AND w.WellType = 'gs' THEN 'Active Gas Storage Wells'
                                    WHEN w.WellStatus = 'a' AND w.WellType = 'ws' THEN 'Active Water Source Wells'
                                    WHEN w.WellStatus = 'a' AND w.WellType = 'tw' THEN 'Active Test Holes'
                                    WHEN w.WellStatus = 'i' AND w.WellType = 'wi' THEN 'Inactive Water Injection Wells'
                                    WHEN w.WellStatus = 'i' AND w.WellType = 'gi' THEN 'Inactive Gas Injection Wells'
                                    WHEN w.WellStatus = 'i' AND w.WellType = 'wd' THEN 'Inactive Water Disposal Wells'
                                    WHEN w.WellStatus = 'i' AND w.WellType = 'gs' THEN 'Inactive Gas Storage Wells'
                                    WHEN w.WellStatus = 'i' AND w.WellType = 'ws' THEN 'Inactive Water Source Wells'
                                    WHEN w.WellStatus = 'i' AND w.WellType = 'tw' THEN 'Inactive Test Holes'
                                    WHEN w.WellStatus = 'ta' THEN 'Temporarily-Abandoned Wells'
                                    WHEN w.WellStatus = 'pa' THEN 'Plugged and Abandoned Wells'
                                    ELSE NULL
                                END
        ) x
    WHERE x.WellCategory IS NOT NULL
    -----------------
    UNION ALL
    -----------------
    SELECT w.LeaseType, x.WellCategory
    FROM cte_Wells w
        CROSS APPLY (
            SELECT WellCategory = CASE 
                                    WHEN w.LateralStatus = 'NEW' THEN 'New Permits - Not Yet Approved'
                                    WHEN w.LateralStatus = 'APD' THEN 'Permits Approved - Not Yet Commenced'
                                    WHEN w.LateralStatus = 'DRL' THEN 'Drilling Commenced - Not Yet Completed'
                                    WHEN w.LateralStatus = 'OPS' THEN 'Drilling Operations Suspended'
                                    ELSE NULL
                                END
        ) x
    WHERE x.WellCategory IS NOT NULL
    -----------------
    UNION ALL
    -----------------
    SELECT w.LeaseType, WellCategory = 'Open Orphan Wells (no known operator)'
    FROM cte_Wells w
    WHERE w.WellStatus IN ('drl','ops','p','s','ta','pai','pii','sai','sii','a','i') AND w.Operator = 101600
    -----------------
    UNION ALL
    -----------------
    SELECT w.LeaseType, WellCategory = 'Total Holes Not Yet Completed'
    FROM cte_Wells w
    WHERE w.WellStatus IN ('drl','ops')
    -----------------
    UNION ALL
    -----------------
    SELECT w.LeaseType, WellCategory = 'Total Wells Capable of Production'
    FROM cte_Wells w
    WHERE (w.WellStatus IN ('p','s') AND w.WellType <> 'LI') OR w.WellStatus IN ('pai','pii','sai','sii')
    -----------------
    UNION ALL
    -----------------
    SELECT w.LeaseType, WellCategory = 'Total Non-Plugged Wells'
    FROM cte_Wells w
    WHERE (w.WellStatus IN ('p','s') AND w.WellType <> 'LI') OR w.WellStatus IN ('drl','ops','ta','pai','pii','sai','sii','a','i')
    -----------------
    UNION ALL
    -----------------
    SELECT w.LeaseType, WellCategory = 'Total Wells Drilled'
    FROM cte_Wells w
    WHERE (w.WellStatus IN ('p','s') AND w.WellType <> 'LI') or w.WellStatus IN ('drl','ops','ta','pai','pii','sai','sii','a','i','pa')
) dt
GROUP BY dt.WellCategory
ORDER BY dt.WellCategory DESC
```

I've checked the results of this query against your sample data and proposed expected results, and they appear to match. So this will get you what you want. However, since I don't know the data, you'll need to inspect it for logic errors, and performance.

NOTE: The results of this query do not produce counts for empty categories. If that is something you need, then comment on this solution and I can fix it. The fix is to add a table with all categories, then LEFT JOIN to that the results of the counts.

Comment: This is basically a much more long winded way of doing what my answer is doing that almost certainly won't be as efficient to execute.

Comment: @iamdave your answer doesn't produce their expected results

Comment: @iamdave I'm also not sure what the point of your comment is other than to bash someone elses attempt to help. If it doesn't work, or is less efficient, then it's up to the OP (and the community) to test the different answers they receive, determine what works best for them, and then vote the answer that they felt was the best solution to their problem.

Comment: *your answer doesn't produce their expected results* - No not exactly, but SO is not a script writing service and I have provided explanation as to why I have not included the `pivot`.  Aside from a `pivot` and `rollup` (which I think should be left outside the SQL script) my answer is producing the required data.

Comment: @iamdave your answer doesn't require a `pivot` or a `rollup`. All you have to do to is place it in a sub-query and add their outer `GROUP BY` and `SUM` operations and you would produce the exact results they're asking for...Even if your answer is more efficient, mine will likely get voted the answer due to being more complete. Make that change and then you'd be right, it would be more efficient, AND it would produce their expected results (minus empty categories, which mine suffers from as well).

Comment: *All you have to do to is place it in a sub-query and add their outer GROUP BY and SUM operations* - This is just manually pivoting the data, which is even more difficult to maintain in the long term than using a standard `pivot`.  This is why any pivot or rollup should be left to the presentation layer.

Comment: This method works for the sample data set I could provide but when I run it on the full data set, the counts are high because when the HWell and HConstruct are joined, it introduces duplicates in the HWell.WellID column.  I know I have to use DISTINCT w.WellID to remody this problem but I think a significant chunk of the query may have to be modified to count WellID's.

Answer (score -1):

One way in which you could do this would be to generate a row for each criteria and then aggregate up those that return a match, which can be done using `cross apply` and a `values` table generator that ensures all your `case` expressions are evaluated for all wells.

This approach at present assumes that each well only has the one `WellCategory` value.  If there can be more than one then you will need to make those changes yourself.  I also haven't wrapped the output in a `pivot` as I think this is generally something best done in your presentation layer rather than the raw SQL.

I suggest keeping the SQL output in this format as presentation tools are much better at dynamically handling new categories (e.g. a new `LeaseType` is added) than SQL is, which in this normalised format wouldn't require a change in either the script or the presentation layer, barring any bespoke labels.

If you want to retain the pivoted output, you can simply wrap this query in your current outer `select`:

### Query

```
select c.LeaseType
      ,cat.WellCategory
      ,count(w.PKey) as Wells
from @HWell as w
    left join @HConstruct as c
        on w.Pkey = c.WellKey
    cross apply(values(case when w.WellStatus = 'p' AND w.WellType = 'gw' OR ((w.WellStatus = 'pai' OR w.WellStatus = 'pii') AND (w.WellType = 'gwi' OR w.WellType = 'ggi' OR w.WellType = 'gwd')) then 'Producing Gas Wells' end)
                     ,(case when w.WellStatus = 'p' AND w.WellType = 'ow' OR ((w.WellStatus = 'pai' OR w.WellStatus = 'pii') AND (w.WellType = 'owi' OR w.WellType = 'ogi' OR w.WellType = 'owd')) then 'Producing Oil Wells' end) -- Need to count DISTINCT WellID's to get to 4770
                     ,(case when w.WellStatus = 's' AND w.WellType = 'ow' OR ((w.WellStatus = 'sai' OR w.WellStatus = 'sii') AND (w.WellType = 'owi' OR w.WellType = 'ogi' OR w.WellType = 'owd')) then 'Shut-In Oil Wells' end)
                     ,(case when w.WellStatus = 's' AND w.WellType = 'gw' OR ((w.WellStatus = 'sai' OR w.WellStatus = 'sii') AND (w.WellType = 'gwi' or w.WellType = 'ggi' or w.WellType = 'gwd')) then 'Shut-In Gas Wells' end)
                     ,(case when w.WellStatus = 'a' AND w.WellType = 'wi' then 'Active Water Injection Wells' end)
                     ,(case when w.WellStatus = 'a' AND w.WellType = 'gi' then 'Active Gas Injection Wells' end)
                     ,(case when w.WellStatus = 'a' AND w.WellType = 'wd' then 'Active Water Disposal Wells' end)
                     ,(case when w.WellStatus = 'a' AND w.WellType = 'gs' then 'Active Gas Storage Wells' end)
                     ,(case when w.WellStatus = 'a' AND w.WellType = 'ws' then 'Active Water Source Wells' end)
                     ,(case when w.WellStatus = 'a' AND w.WellType = 'tw' then 'Active Test Holes' end)
                     ,(case when w.WellStatus = 'i' AND w.WellType = 'wi' then 'Inactive Water Injection Wells' end)
                     ,(case when w.WellStatus = 'i' AND w.WellType = 'gi' then 'Inactive Gas Injection Wells' end)
                     ,(case when w.WellStatus = 'i' AND w.WellType = 'wd' then 'Inactive Water Disposal Wells' end)
                     ,(case when w.WellStatus = 'i' AND w.WellType = 'gs' then 'Inactive Gas Storage Wells' end)
                     ,(case when w.WellStatus = 'i' AND w.WellType = 'ws' then 'Inactive Water Source Wells' end)
                     ,(case when w.WellStatus = 'i' AND w.WellType = 'tw' then 'Inactive Test Holes' end)
                     ,(case when w.WellStatus = 'ta' then 'Temporarily-Abandoned Wells' end)
                     ,(case when w.WellStatus = 'pa' then 'Plugged and Abandoned Wells' end)
                     ,(case when c.LateralStatus = 'NEW' then 'New Permits - Not Yet Approved' end)
                     ,(case when c.LateralStatus = 'APD' then 'Permits Approved - Not Yet Commenced' end)
                     ,(case when c.LateralStatus = 'DRL' then 'Drilling Commenced - Not Yet Completed' end)
                     ,(case when c.LateralStatus = 'OPS' then 'Drilling Operations Suspended' end)
                     ,(case when w.WellStatus IN ('drl','ops','p','s','ta','pai','pii','sai','sii','a','i') AND w.Operator = 101600 then 'Open Orphan Wells (no known operator)' end)
                     ,(case when w.WellStatus IN ('drl','ops') then 'Total Holes Not Yet Completed' end)
                     ,(case when ((w.WellStatus = 'p' or w.WellStatus = 's') AND w.WellType <> 'LI') OR (w.WellStatus = 'pai' OR w.WellStatus = 'pii' OR w.WellStatus = 'sai' OR w.WellStatus = 'sii') then 'Total Wells Capable of Production' end)
                     ,(case when (w.WellStatus = 'drl' OR w.WellStatus = 'ops' OR ((w.WellStatus = 'p' or w.WellStatus = 's') AND w.WellType <> 'LI') OR w.WellStatus = 'ta' OR w.WellStatus = 'pai' OR w.WellStatus = 'pii' OR w.WellStatus = 'sai' OR w.WellStatus = 'sii' OR w.WellStatus = 'a' OR w.WellStatus = 'i') then 'Total Non-Plugged Wells' end)
                     ,(case when (w.WellStatus = 'drl' or w.WellStatus = 'ops' or ((w.WellStatus = 'p' or w.WellStatus = 's') and w.WellType <> 'LI') or w.WellStatus = 'ta' or w.WellStatus = 'pai' or w.WellStatus = 'pii' or w.WellStatus = 'sai' or w.WellStatus = 'sii' or w.WellStatus = 'a' or w.WellStatus = 'i' or w.WellStatus = 'pa') then 'Total Wells Drilled' end)
               ) as cat(WellCategory)
where cat.WellCategory is not null
group by c.LeaseType
        ,cat.WellCategory
order by c.LeaseType
        ,Wells desc;
```

### Output

| LeaseType | WellCategory | Wells |
| --- | --- | --- |
| F | Total Wells Drilled | 183 |
| F | Total Non-Plugged Wells | 123 |
| F | Total Wells Capable of Production | 108 |
| F | Plugged and Abandoned Wells | 60 |
| F | Producing Gas Wells | 59 |
| F | Shut-In Gas Wells | 19 |
| F | Producing Oil Wells | 18 |
| F | Inactive Water Injection Wells | 11 |
| F | Shut-In Oil Wells | 10 |
| F | Permits Approved - Not Yet Commenced | 4 |
| F | Total Holes Not Yet Completed | 2 |
| F | Drilling Commenced - Not Yet Completed | 1 |
| F | Open Orphan Wells (no known operator) | 1 |
| F | Temporarily-Abandoned Wells | 1 |
| F | Active Water Injection Wells | 1 |
| F | Drilling Operations Suspended | 1 |
| I | Total Wells Drilled | 67 |
| I | Total Non-Plugged Wells | 52 |
| I | Total Wells Capable of Production | 38 |
| I | Producing Oil Wells | 25 |
| I | Plugged and Abandoned Wells | 15 |
| I | Shut-In Oil Wells | 10 |
| I | Active Water Injection Wells | 5 |
| I | Inactive Water Injection Wells | 5 |
| I | Total Holes Not Yet Completed | 4 |
| I | Drilling Operations Suspended | 3 |
| I | Permits Approved - Not Yet Commenced | 2 |
| I | Shut-In Gas Wells | 2 |
| I | New Permits - Not Yet Approved | 1 |
| I | Producing Gas Wells | 1 |
| I | Drilling Commenced - Not Yet Completed | 1 |
| IP | Permits Approved - Not Yet Commenced | 2 |
| P | Total Wells Drilled | 38 |
| P | Total Non-Plugged Wells | 19 |
| P | Plugged and Abandoned Wells | 19 |
| P | Total Wells Capable of Production | 17 |
| P | Producing Oil Wells | 10 |
| P | Producing Gas Wells | 5 |
| P | Permits Approved - Not Yet Commenced | 4 |
| P | Total Holes Not Yet Completed | 2 |
| P | Drilling Commenced - Not Yet Completed | 2 |
| P | Shut-In Gas Wells | 1 |
| P | Shut-In Oil Wells | 1 |
| S | Total Wells Drilled | 57 |
| S | Total Non-Plugged Wells | 38 |
| S | Total Wells Capable of Production | 35 |
| S | Producing Gas Wells | 25 |
| S | Plugged and Abandoned Wells | 19 |
| S | Producing Oil Wells | 6 |
| S | Shut-In Gas Wells | 4 |
| S | Permits Approved - Not Yet Commenced | 2 |
| S | Inactive Water Injection Wells | 2 |
| S | Active Water Disposal Wells | 1 |